# Is it possible to use Lync Server 2013 as a UCMA application server also?

Tags: c#, ucma, lync-server-2013

I'm new to UCMA and I'm trying to set up an environment to build UCMA applications.

I have 2 Windows 2008 Servers, one for Active Directory DC and an other for Lync  2013 Server, can I use either of these machines to also run/develop my UCMA applications by installing VS and UCMA 4.0 SDK ?

Or will I need a separate Windows 2008 server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your Lync Server as the App server, I can't find proof but I'm pretty sure that Microsoft advise against this and although I suspect it is fine in a lab environment you could come across undocumented issues.